# How come we get accepted after one interview on skype? Something is fishy

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

## First company

I had an interview with a start-up company for the position of data-scientist. I started by describing my previous experiences. I described the problem then solutions that I applied. then they started by asking me technical questions:

- What are the drawbacks of Principal component analysis? I answered correctly
- How can you link c++ and java? I also answered correctly

They also asked me are you ready to take the risk of leaving your previous work and coming to a start-up which is full of risks. I answered yes I am ready to take that risk because the end result will be good.

> The interview was done with the **co-founders** of the company. One is
> specialized in Machine learning and the other in programming more
> specifically Java. The interview lasted for 40 minutes. As I mentioned earlier
> it went really smooth. In the end they asked for the Salary. I said that I
> want $40k per year.

.

**The next day:** They called me and extended a job offer with my requested Salary ($40k).

---

## Second company

In the second start-up so far I have had two interviews: one with the Human resources the second with a Researcher in machine learning. I nailed all the questions. Next week I have another interview with the **last boss** (The most difficult one)  If I pass  the  last boss they will offer a position.

> I didn't chicken out and I passed the interview yesterday with a
> professor. The questions were brutal. It was good though and they contacted
> me today to go to their startup and meet the team.
>
> I learned something important. The professor told me That I have 2/3
> knowledge but I lack 1/3 theory in Machine learning. I contradicted
> him and he cornered me. In the end he told me I care for you this is
> why I told you this and all what I had to say is yes you are right
> I'll improve myself. It was really interesting and humbling.

I did like it. It gave me self confidence and I knew my limits. I'll be going next Monday to their startup to meet the team.

---

## Questions

- Is there something fishy with the first company? I really found it weird that it went so fast.
- Would you do go on with the second start-up and do the interview?

Comment: "Is there something fishy with the first company?" Depends on your definition of fishy. I don't find anything fishy there, they made you an offer, if you don't feel comfortable, don't accept it. "Would you do go on with the second start-up and do the interview?" I would, unless there is a good reason not to. It is not clear what you want us to help with, voted to close.

Comment: There's just not enough information here to know if something is fishy or not.

Comment: Can you clarify, did they call you worthless in the first startup where you passed the interview easily but then didn't meet their expectations? Or was that in your job before the first startup?

Comment: You didn't explain who was in the interview with the first startup.  If it's just one HR person, then yes that would be fishy.  If it's one person you'd work with, less so, and if it's several people, quite normal and even efficient.  Also, no point in turning down the second startup just yet.  You haven't even met who you'll be working for, and who knows, you might like that person a lot.  Also, you can always negotiate a better deal with the first startup if the second makes you an offer.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh The interview was done with the co-founders of the company. One is specialized in Machine learning and the other in programming more specifically Java. you are right i'll do the other interview anyway. it's better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes legitimate high paying positions need to be filled in a hurry, particularly with startups. I have seen plenty of positions filled after a single round of interviews. If this is your only concern then you may be worrying unnecessarily.

If it's too much of a worry then carry on with other interviews.

Comment: thank you @Kilisi. yes i am worried for nothing. you are right. it's just a good position and I was excited.

Comment: i made my decision. I'll send an email to other startup to tell them I found another company. it's not wrong yes?

Comment: Why not do the other interviews anyway? You'll have a probation period in the first startup in which to change your mind. Although since the offered so fast they might want you to start immediately, which is a good thing, sooner you start sooner you get paid.

Comment: yes i'll do it anyway. i have nothing to lose. you are right